# Angular 2 Issue with http requests on firefox

Tags: angular, typescript

I have very strange issue with Angular 2 application on firefox and all ios browsers (firefox , safari)

When user enter `/reports` route in my application i'm calling my rest api via  `ngOnInit` method to get json data.

This is the part of my ngOnInit method which is handling data load:

```
ngOnInit() {
//this.service is my service to get reports
    this.service.getReports(this.categoryId).subscribe(res => {
        this.testReports = res;
    }
}
```

after I get response i'm rendering my reports in html file:

```
<div class="cat-item-holder" *ngFor="let singleCategory of testReports; let i=index">
{{singleCategory.name}}
</div>
```

In chrome I can see that all reports are visible immediately after i enter `/reports` page. In firefox and safari I can see that application 'hangs up' and i have to double-triple click somewhere on the page to see results from my api.

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue ? Maybe this is something with `ngOnInit` method ?

---

My angular-cli.json file:

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.22-1",
    "name": "APPNAME"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "assets/config/config_google.json",
        "../backend/web/uploads"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main-polymer.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "assets/css/styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
         "assets/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js",
         "../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"
      ],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": true,
    "inline": {
      "style": true,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": true,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": true,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

-- 
My package json file

```
{
  "name": "front",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-alpha.11-3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.2.3",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.2.1",
    "@vaadin/angular2-polymer": "^1.0.0-rc1",
    "angular2-fontawesome": "~0.7.0",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.21",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.26",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "ng-disable-scroll": "^0.1.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.16",
    "ng2-dropdown": "0.0.15",
    "ng2-filter-pipe": "^0.1.4",
    "ng2-page-scroll": "3.2.3",
    "ng2-parallax": "^0.3.0",
    "ng2-parallax-scroll": "^0.4.0",
    "ng2-sticky-kit": "^1.1.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.21",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
}
```

and my reports service implementation:

```
import {Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, Response , URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { MainService } from './main.service';

@Injectable()
export class ReportsService {
   constructor(private http:Http , private mainService:MainService) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  getReports(categoryId) : Observable<Response> {
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('cat', categoryId);
    params.set('user', this.mainService.getMainUserMail());
    return this.http.get(this.mainService.getServiceUrl()+'/reports/' , {headers: this.mainService.getHeaders() , search: params}).map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

In My reports page on firefox i can see little scroll in right upper corner of loading section [image: reports page] , If i click few times on this scroll , reports are rendering in firefox properly , maybe this is some DOM related issue ?

---

Okay I've found workaround for this issue,in `app.component.ts` I've add

```
import {ApplicationRef} from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private _applicationRef: ApplicationRef, private _router: Router) {
        setInterval(() => {
              this._applicationRef.tick();
           }, 5000);
    }

}
```

And in `reports.ts` component:

```
 constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        setInterval(() => {
           this.ref.detectChanges();
         }, 5000);
}
```

Now after 5 sec of page load in firefox i have little hang up of browser , and results are successfully rendered , but does anyone  know how to prevent this hang up ?

Comment: Are you using a different kind of `ChangeDetectionStrategy` in your component or one of its parents?

Comment: Hi @PierreDuc , I'm not using any kind of ChangeDetectionStrategy  in my application , should i use one ?

Comment: @PierreDuc I've tried to use ChangeDetectionStrategy in one of my components and with ChangeDetectionStrategy .onPush  application also hangs up in chrome

Comment: If you are using no special `ChangeDetection`, then everything should work as is. What version of angular are you using? Is your browser up to date? Can you show me your `getReports` implementation?

Comment: @PierreDuc I'm using angular-2 cli version with polymer , In my post i've pasted my angular-cli,json , tsconfig.json and my service. Also , my browser is up to date

Comment: I know this could be useless, but I'll ask you anyway. Have you tried placing an *ngIf="testReports" before the *ngFor statement?

Comment: @AndrewReborn ngIf is working properly , but still no results in firefox 
Also console.log of my http request results normal json object in chrome and firefox , so this is not api related issiue

Comment: @woj_jas everything looks good. only thing that can be the issue here is using polymer with angular. Try updating to @angular/2.4.5

Comment: I'm trying to update angular , now I found that in firefox during loading http request i can see little scroll bar , if I click on this scroll bar few times , reports are rendering properly , but i don't know why they are not working without clicking action

Comment: @PierreDuc 
I found workaround for this, can you please read last section of my main post and see if i can prevent browser hang up ?

Answer (score 0):

Posting it as an 'answer', but it's more a workaround based on your own workaround. I still think the problem is residing from `polymer` in combination with angular's change detection.

```
@Component({...})
export class ReportsComponent {

    constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.getReports(this.categoryId).subscribe(res => {
            this.testReports = res;
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Not entirely sure if the `setTimeout` is going to be necessary, but that's for you to find out. This will trigger a change detection on this component and its children. Basically what you are doing with your mouse clicks and mouse movements, is triggering angular's change detection.