# Angular 4 Issue with api requests on firefox

Tags: node.js, angular

I have very strange issue with Angular 4 application on firefox

I have created an angular application with toggle button namely "prod" and "dev" at the bottom of the page, also I have added a button in the app. If the toggle points to the prod it serves from the production server API (www.prod_server.com/get),

If the toggle points to the dev it serves from the development server API (www.dev_server.com/get),

Both are different API.

My question is, toggle switch is working fine in Google chrome and Internet explorer, but the same is not working in Firefox. I have searched for the solution but the below link is not working correctly.

[Angular 2 Issue with http requests on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41896925/angular-2-issue-with-http-requests-on-firefox)

Comment: Stop using Jquery in an angular app

Comment: You have a strange issue, may we know which one? Also yes, absolutely stop using jQuery in an Angular app.

Comment: What does the API console show?
200 a success? or 400 a bad request?

Comment: Pure instinct here cause you haven’t actually posted an issue, but I’m guessing that you’re using jquery xhr methods which have a known issue in iOS and safari where they don’t parse the response body to json without the content type explicitly set, and it needs to be done manually.